# How could I pass a sql script as an argument to a bash file?

Tags: sql, bash

I need to pass a sql script as an argument to a bash file. My bash file is as below

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
   echo "Usage: databasename, tablename, script"
exit 1
fi

export DB=$1
export PWD=absc

/research/util/Unload.py -e -d "|" -t $2 -c "MM/DD/YYYY" -s $3
```

I execute the bash file in this way:

```
./UnloadToInfx.sh "db_name" "mytable" "select * from mytable where city='LA' and date='05/22/2018'"
```

It prop up error regrading to $3 which is the sql script. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Probably need to quote that $3: `/research/util/Unload.py -e -d "|" -t $2 -c "MM/DD/YYYY" -s "$3"`. Otherwise the python command would literally be: `/research/util/Unload.py -e -d "|" -t mytable -c "MM/DD/YYYY" -s select * from mytable where city='LA' and date='05/22/2018'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script like this (encapsulate bare $1,2,3 references to "$1", "$2" etc.) The reason is that encapsulating them will present them as a unit for the program that you give the argument to.

Otherwise a string with spaces will be presented as multiple arguments and any glob characters like *? will be expanded to filenames in your current directory, which you don't want.

Even so, take care that your arguments don't start with a (-) hyphen, because then they might still be interpreted as option switches .

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
   echo "Usage: databasename, tablename, script"
exit 1
fi

export DB="$1"
export PWD=absc

/research/util/Unload.py -e -d "|" -t "$2" -c "MM/DD/YYYY" -s "$3"
```